# How do I set the read-only 'frame_duration' property of an image sequence with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I try to load in an image sequence as background image with python.
I managed to load it and set the source as sequence, however when i try to set its frame duration according to the number of images in the sequence, I get an error saying that the attribute is read-only.
Can I change this attribute in another way and if not, how can I tell Blender to use it as image sequence?

My code so far:

```
path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\image0001.png"
img = bpy.data.images.load(path)
img.source = "SEQUENCE"
```

Prints an error:

```
img.frame_duration = 50

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "frame_duration" from "Image" is read-
only
```

Answer (score 1):

frame duration is a calculated value and cannot be set directly.

```
frame_duration = frame_end - frame_start
```

In order to change the `frame_duration` of the sequence you need to change the `frame_start` and/or `frame_end`. This makes sense as Blender cannot decide for you which frames you don't want to see (cut from the start or cut from the end, or from the middle, or ....).

```
# cut the start of the sequence
desired_frame_duration = 50
img.frame_start += img.frame_end - desired_frame_duration

# cut the end of the sequence
desired_frame_duration = 50
img.frame_end = img.frame_start + desired_frame_duration
```

Comment: Seems the frame_start and frame_end no longer exist for image datablocks in Blender 2.8x. Is there another way this can be achieved?

Comment: try to use image_user. I add image to ShaderNodeTexEnvironment then ShaderNodeTexEnvironment.image_user.frame_start can bet set.

Answer (score 1):

If the image editor is used in one of the visible areas of the current workspace, it can be iterated through [bpy.context.screen.areas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type) to find the one with type `IMAGE_EDITOR`. The image that is shown in the editor can be set through the [space](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.image) of the area.

```
path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\image0001.png"
img = bpy.data.images.load(path)

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        area.spaces.active.image = img
        img.source = 'SEQUENCE'
        area.spaces.active.image_user.frame_duration = 800
```

And if the plugin is in context, i.e in menu or button of a viwer node then there is no need to iterate through anymore. As the cursor is already in context menu. In this case the plugin script should be:

```
path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\image0001.png"
img = bpy.data.images.load(path)

bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image = img
img.source = 'SEQUENCE'
bpy.context.area.spaces.active.image_user.frame_duration = 800
```